# When intergrating the small element of rod to find the moment of inertia of a rod, how can the the perpendicular distance be takes as negative?

Tags: integration, rotational-kinematics, moment-of-inertia

[image]

In the image, the perpendicular distance x is taken as -l/2 and l/2 where l is length. how can the perpendicular distance x be taken as negative(distance cannot be negative). Is it a inaccurate method to make the integration easier or is there any other reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They should have used perpendicular displacement (not distance),
where $x=0$ at the line AB, and $x$ increases to the right.

So, your concern is appropriate!

Answer (score 0):

Distances can't be negative, true. But then physicists love symmetry and exploit it.

The *length* of the rod is *distance* technically.

$L = x_2 - x_1$ must be a positive number (here $x_1 = -l/2$ and $x_2 = + l/2$

Because $L = +l/2 - (-l/2) = + l$. The length of the rod is a positive number as this represents distance.

In short, it's a matter of convenience that we use negative numbers for $x$ since all they represent is the *abscissa* in the coordinate plane. The length between two points on a coordinate plane can never be negative especially for a quantity like distance that can only take positive values (because it's a physical quantity that has no meaning if it were negative, unless we were talking about displacement, which is a vector quantity).

Comment: In the image,x= perpendicular distance from line AB .I think they are wrong in saying   that        x=-l/2(as l is positive).they should have said that x=perpendicular displacement from AB instead of distance.am I correct?

Comment: Yes, to be honest,  your doubt is valid. The question in the book could have been more clear and specific as to what $-l/2$ means.